# How can I discover an "object access flag" that is apparently needed when deleting a Quickbooks invoice data entension using QBSDK

Tags: vb.net, sdk, quickbooks

I am using the QuickBooks QBFC12 SDK, and specifically, I am attempting to delete a "data extension" on an invoice in QB.

Some of the time the following VB.NET code will work, but many times it doesn't:

```
Dim objRequest As IMsgSetRequest
Dim objDatExtAdder As IDataExtAdd
Dim objResponse As IMsgSetResponse
Dim objOurResponse As IResponse
Dim objInvoiceQuery As IInvoiceQuery
Dim objInvoiceRetList As IInvoiceRetList
Dim objInvoiceRet As IInvoiceRet
Dim szInvoiceTxnID As String = ""
Dim objDataExtDel As IDataExtDel

' Check to see if the invoice is already on file.
objInvoiceQuery = objRequest.AppendInvoiceQueryRq
objInvoiceQuery.ORInvoiceQuery.InvoiceFilter.MaxReturned.SetValue(1)
objInvoiceQuery.IncludeLineItems.SetValue(True)
objInvoiceQuery.IncludeLinkedTxns.SetValue(True)
objInvoiceQuery.ORInvoiceQuery.InvoiceFilter.ORRefNumberFilter.RefNumberFilter.MatchCriterion.SetValue(ENMatchCriterion.mcEndsWith)
objInvoiceQuery.ORInvoiceQuery.InvoiceFilter.ORRefNumberFilter.RefNumberFilter.RefNumber.SetValue(szQBInvoiceNumber)
objResponse = objSessionManager.DoRequests(objRequest)
objOurResponse = objResponse.ResponseList.GetAt(0)

If objOurResponse.StatusCode = 0 Then
  ' Lock onto the invoice.
  objInvoiceRetList = objOurResponse.Detail

  If objInvoiceRetList.Count > 0 Then
    ' The invoice already exists.
    objInvoiceRet = objInvoiceRetList.GetAt(0)
    szInvoiceTxnID = objInvoiceRet.TxnID.GetValue
  End If
End If

objRequest.ClearRequests()

' Remove any previous value.
objRequest = objSessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 11, 0)
objRequest.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeStop

objDataExtDel = objRequest.AppendDataExtDelRq()
objDataExtDel.OwnerID.SetValue("0")
objDataExtDel.ORListTxn.TxnDataExt.TxnDataExtType.SetValue(ENTxnDataExtType.tdetInvoice)
objDataExtDel.ORListTxn.TxnDataExt.TxnID.SetValue(szInvoiceTxnID)
objDataExtDel.DataExtName.SetValue(szDataExtensionName)

objResponse = objSessionManager.DoRequests(objRequest)
objOurResponse = objResponse.ResponseList.GetAt(0)

If objOurResponse.StatusCode = 0 Then
  Debug.Print("Worked")
Else
  Debug.Print("Didn't work")
End If
```

On the occasions where it reports "Didn't Work," `objourresponse.StatusMessage` returns:

> The necessary QuickBooks **object access** flag was not set in the attribute definition for an attribute. QuickBooks error message: Unknown Error

I have tried to understand what the "Object Access Flag" is and where it can be found, and I have searched on Google and the Intuit developer's site for more information, but I can't find anything.

Can someone help with understanding what this is, how I can get past this issue, and how I can consistently delete this data extension whenever necessary?

Comment: This almost sounds like a bug in the SDK. Try using QBXML for the request and see if you get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

After a **LOT** of trial and error, I believe I have struck on a solution.

The particular extension was part of a drop-down selector that I have displayed on the invoice. Some of the valid values are "Printed" or "Shipped". Formerly, when I went to change the value in the extension, I was first deleting the extension using `AppendDataExtDelRq`, then adding it back in with the new value using `AppendDataExtAddRq`.

I was able to get the value to change if, instead of using the delete/add combination, I used `AppendDataExtModRq` and simply changed the value.

I still think there is a bug in the SDK like @InteXX suspects, but I also noticed that **IF** I set the extension to a pre-defined value in the drop-down, then all is good. **BUT**, if I try to set the extension to a value that isn't pre-defined in QB for that extension/drop-down, then I get the exact same error:

> The necessary QuickBooks **object access** flag was not set in the attribute definition for an attribute. QuickBooks error message: Unknown Error

So the upshot is that it is working now by using the MOD and not the DELETE/ADD approach, but make sure you set the value to a pre-defined value.